# Group By specific element of inner array

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query

I am trying to achieve the results as mentioned below through a single query:

> Get all results where *pub.type* is *deb* and *pub.name* is *Mzn* and group them by *pub.name* where *pub.type* is *cred*

Here is example data:

```
[
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Mzn"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "Alf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Mzn"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "Alf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Mzn"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "All"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Mzn"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "All"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Mzn"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "All"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Mzn"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "Hab"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Hab"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "Alf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Hab"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "Alf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "All"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "Alf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "addr": "address1",
    "book": "book1",
    "pub": [
      {
        "type": "deb",
        "name": "Mzn"
      },
      {
        "type": "cred",
        "name": "Hab"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So far I have come to the query written below. First part is working fine inside `$match` block, the second one is not. It is grouping data by the array, but I want it to group data by element of the object of the array where it should meet a particular condition (which I have written earlier).

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
[ 
  { 
     "$match":{ 
        "pub":{ 
           $elemMatch:{ 
              "type":"deb",    //This part is working fine
              "name":"Mzn"
           }
        }
     }
  },
  { 
     "$group":{ 
        "_id":{ 
           "object":"$pub.name"
        },
        "object":{ 
           "$push":"$$ROOT"
        }
     }
  }
])
```

I have tried to use `$unwind` but it is just splitting it into objects of each element of array.

This is the result generated by above query: [result by above query](https://api.myjson.com/bins/18ls7e)

This is the result I need: [desired result](https://api.myjson.com/bins/ih2gq)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The json data in "desired result", is this your final output required or is it "group them by pub.name where pub.type is cred"?

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to be a roundabout way to get the answers, but this works for me.

The unwinding `pub1` may rise problems in large datasets

```
db.getCollection('books').aggregate(  [ 
   { 
      "$match":{ 
         "pub":{ 
            $elemMatch:{ 
               "type":"deb",
               "name":"Mzn"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { 
      "$project":{ 
         "_id":"$_id",
         "addr":"$addr",
         "book":"$book",
         "pub":"$pub",
         "pub1":"$pub"
      }
   },
   { 
      "$unwind":'$pub1'
   },
   { 
      "$match":{ 
         "pub1.type":"cred"
      }
   },
   { 
      "$group":{ 
         "_id":{ 
            "name":"$pub1.name"
         },
         "object":{ 
            "$push":{ 
               "_id":"$$ROOT._id",
               "addr":"$$ROOT.addr",
               "book":"$$ROOT.book",
               "pub":"$$ROOT.pub"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```